# Threading.start() does not always begin the thread's process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a program that I need to gather and display data and I'm dealing with vast amounts of data, so I am using threading to speed it up.

Problem is, when debugging sometimes running `thread.start()` will not immediately call `thread.run()`, as it should.

Sometimes `thread.start()` will immediately call `thread.run()`, other times thread.run() will be called after `thread2.run()` finishes executing for example.

Sometimes it seems like `thread.run()` is never called and the program times out when trying to join the threads.

```py
def do_work(self, values, toSearch):
    threads = []
    for i in range(3):
        query = MyThreadClass(values, toSearch)
        query.start()
        threads.append(query)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
        if t.is_alive():
            print "Thread is still alive!"
#           At this point at least one thread is still alive often, however
#           not ALL the time
```

I would expect each call to `query.start()` to run `query.run()` immediately, except that's not the case.

By the time I get to `.join()` and there's still a thread alive, my program will timeout.

Debugging shows that each one that calls `run()` will be stopped, as it should, but ones that never called `run()` will not be stopped, and hang up on `join()`.

Why does this happen/how can I fix timeouts on `join()`?

Comment: How are your threads supposed to "end"? Do you signal them or do they just complete by themselves after doing one thing?

Comment: Are you sure the thread is not actually running when the timeout occurs? Maybe the work is actually just taking a long time.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the `run()` method is overridden and as per docs, when reaching the end of the `run()` method the thread will stop @Will

Comment: The strange thing is it shouldn't be. The code isn't implemented correctly as it is, so only Thread0 does all the work which takes some amount of time. Thread2 & Thread3 don't do any work, and autoexit, but since the call to `Thread2/3.start()` is either delayed or missing, it leads me to believe that that may not be the issue @Blorgbeard

Comment: In which case Thread0 is taking too long. Also, remember each thread will get scheduled by the os so run() won't happen synchronously

Comment: Could you write up an explanation of that to serve as an answer? @Will

Comment: [Dan](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) does it better than I ever could